# MAMP PRO - Trouble making hosts file accessible on Windows

Tags: windows, mamp, hosts

Today I've been starting to use MAMP PRO for Windows, it's in alpha right now.
But im trying to make Dynamic DNS work, which doesn't seem to work for me.

Every time I start up MAMP PRO, I get the following error:

```
MAMP PRO has detected that access to hosts file is blocked. MAMP PRO needs access to hosts file to work properly. It is probably blocked with Antivirus program or restricted user privillages. Please close MAMP PRO, set your Antivirus program or user privillages (so that access to hosts file is writable) and start MAMP PRO again.
```

I did try toggling my antivirus off, and I did set permissions to writable, executable, readable etc. to every user on my machine.

I also tried to run MAMP PRO as administrator.

Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to edit and save hosts file directly in notepad? (when notepad is run as administrator?) Path on most Windows installations to hosts file is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you unchecked read-only on this file?

1. Make sure file is not read-only. Navigate to %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\ and right-click -> Properties on hosts, and un-check Read-only
2. Take ownership of the file (May be unnecessary, I did this first before finding Read-only). Right-click -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Owner -> Edit, and then select your name and OK out of all prompts.
3. I also gave full permissions to all users on the system, as you mentioned.

I tested this on Windows 7 with MAMP Pro, after experiencing the same problem. This got me up and running, hope it helps.

References:
http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1821155/edit-hosts-file-windows.html